# Saving and opening mhtml file in chrome shows blank page

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Chrome or chromium does not save whole pages in Web archive file mhtml file correctly in most cases.
Opening saved file is somehow corrupted and does rendered blank.
I did some experiments and tried all last versions (85.0.4183.83) on three system to save same "MHTML - Wikipedia" page. I figured out that:

- many pages are not saved correctly
- saved page in Chromium's incognito mode is less smaller, therefore latest is wrong
- Chromium suggests wrong extension. It is saved as .html instead of .mhtml

I do not know why is so difficult to save all resources while traversing DOM and transferred files?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no.

Comment: Not chrome, but works: `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I was a little too early (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML#Google_Chrome) to write comments about WIP features. They have been working on that and in the time of writing (version 102) this answer the code-base matured more.

Although wget is a great tool and with handy options gives you a similar but not same solution. But each way / tool for a different purpose.

So now works for pages I saved. I hope also for yours!